# can't able to connect mysql server connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my code -

public class DataBaseConnection {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nitya", "username", "password");

        Statement s=con.createStatement();

        ResultSet r=s.executeQuery("select * from employee");

        while(r.next()) {
        System.out.println(r.getInt(1));
        }


    }

}
```

The error i am getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ss'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.stc.TestCases.DataBaseConnection.main(DataBaseConnection.java:15)
```

Comment: The answer is in the exception: permission denied. Check that the user host in the users table really is "localhost". Check the grants permission for that user to that database (and possibly table).

Comment: your code has nothing to do with selenium

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL is locally installed and working fine. But in default port localhost:3306 it is not opening. Can you please share which url i should provide in getconnect method? @CrazyMerlin 14